# React Native : how to change <Text> value dynamically

Tags: react-native

I want to change  value dynamically at some event

Event:

```
BackgroundGeolocation.on('location', (location) => {      
    currentDistance =  distance(previousLatitude,previousLongitude,latitude,longitude);

            this.setState({
                text: currentDistance                
            });                                   

    });
<Text>
   Moving : {this.state.text}
</Text>
```

does anyone know how to change text or any other method to achieve?

Comment: What exactly do you want to change? What event?

Comment: `this.setState({text: 'Another Text'})` http://facebook.github.io/react-native/releases/0.38/docs/state.html

Comment: i want to update distance which calculate at my location event
i updated in question

but it give me error called : 
undefined is not a function (evaluating 'this.setState({text:currentDistance})')

Comment: just write a function setState and call it when you want to change a text.
Here is a simple example i make in rnplay : https://rnplay.org/apps/J417aA

Comment: Yes correct i have achieve through with function
thanks @NguyênHoàng

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Below is the example where it uses states for dynamic changing of text value while clicking on it. You can set on any event you want.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import {
   Text,
   View
} from 'react-native'

export default class reactApp extends Component {
   constructor() {
      super()
      this.state = {
         myText: 'My Original Text'
      }
   }
   updateText = () => {
      this.setState({myText: 'My Changed Text'})
   }
   render() {
      return (
         <View>
            <Text onPress = {this.updateText}>
               {this.state.myText}
            </Text>
         </View>
      );
   }
}
```

**EDIT: Using React Hooks**

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';

const ReactApp = () => {
    const [myText, setMyText] = useState("My Original Text");
    return (
        <View>
            <Text onPress = {() => setMyText("My Changed Text")}>
                    {myText}
            </Text>
        </View>
    )
}

export default ReactApp;
```

Comment: I need to write 

updateText = () => {
      this.setState({myText: 'My Changed Text'})
   }

this code inside my event ?

Comment: got it i just need to call updateText() with desired argument
its work men
Love it !!!!
Thank you...

Comment: I need to show the validation message in the text if the input field is empty. Can u refer this and let me know any answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57157692/how-to-show-a-text-as-mandatory-field-in-react-native-text-without-touchable-opa

Answer (score 14):

Use:

```
<TextInput editable={false} ref={component=> this._MyComponent=component}/>
```

instead of:

```
<Text></Text>
```

Then you can change the text this way:

```
onPress= {()=> {
    this._MyComponent.setNativeProps({text:'my new text'});
}
```