# How to change a string in React-Native into a Component?

Tags: react-native

I have a `var str = '<Text> something </Text>'`, can I render it into a Component?

I tried the following, but it doesn't work :(

```
var str = '<Text>test</Text>'
    render(){
        return(
            <Text>{str}</Text>
        )
   }
```

Is there any way to do this, similar to `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` in React?

In my project, I get json by fetch just like

```
{
   content:'<p>example</p>'
}
```

I want to replace the html element `p` or others into `Text`and so on by regular expressions, but the result is a string.

I also tried the `react-native-html-render` but it's document is incomprehensible and doesn't performs well.

Comment: this question is quite similar with this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41139643/react-native-how-to-change-text-value-dynamically/41139864#41139864

Comment: @MonkeyFigaro any updates on this question please, am runing throught the same problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a function that converts the inner html of the response you get into a RN Text element.

```
var str = '<p>something here</p>'

var convertToText = (response) => {
  var text = response.split(/[^A-Za-z]/).filter(x => x !== '').slice(1, -1).join(' ') //gives "something here";
  return <Text>text</Text>;
}

convertToText(str) === <Text>something here</Text>
```

Comment: Thank you, I've already edited my question and could you help me solve this problem?Thanks again.

Comment: updated my answer, you can basically convert them to Text elements using this function, but if you need different elements based on what is in the response then you would need to add some more configurations.

Comment: Actually i realized this only works for one word elements, just updated it to handle any amount of words.

Answer (score 1):

Set it as part of your state (e.g., `this.state.str`). In your constructor, give it a default value (e.g., `this.state = {str: "test"}`). Then in your function that does the fetch, do `setState` to change the value (e.g., `this.setState({str: response})`). Finally, in your render, do this:

```
render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text>{this.state.str}</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  var str = <Text>test</Text>;

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        {str}
      </View>
    );
  }
```

Comment: thx, but in fact it's a response of a fetch, so I couldn't just set the str like what you said...

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the *tag* needs to be incorporated at compile-time, as JSX becomes transpiled into `React.createElement` calls. Or you can write the `React.createElement` calls yourself.

For example, you can create a parser than can walk the JSX tree in your server response. Something like

```
function parseResponseIntoJSXTree (string) {
  // very psuedo example:
  var type = parseJSXTag(string) // produces `Text`
  var props = parseJSXTagProps(string) // produce any attribute=values
  var innerContent = parseJSXContent(string) // produces 'something'
  return React.createElement(type, props, children)
}
```

This only scratches the surface, as you'd need to walk the tree if there are child elements deeper than the root node.

Want my horrible, **horrible** answer?
Include `babel` in your bundle and do:

```
var renderableContent = require('babel-core', {presets: ['react-native'])
  .transform('<Text>something</Text>')
```

Note - I highly discourage this, but it technically would work, unless `babel` requires on node dependencies that won't exist in the runtime (likely).

Comment: Thanks! But it's seems a little hard to me to write the parse. And the _horrible answer_ you said...It **might** be a useable way to be considered.Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

My requirement is similar, to make dynamic screens with arbitrary components, depending on JSON server response. Here is what I did:

```
const blockContent = [
  {
    type: 'text',
    content: 'Some title',
    size: 20,
    color: 'black',
    wrapperPadding: 10
  },
    {
      type: 'text',
      wrapperPadding: 10,
      size: 16,
      color: 'red',
      content: 'Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. '
    },
    {
      type: 'text',
      wrapperPadding: 10,
      size: 16,
      color: 'red',
      content: 'Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. '
    },
    {
      type: 'link',
      content: 'Some link',
      size: 16,
      color: 'blue',
      wrapperPadding: 10,
      url: 'http://www.google.com'
    }
];

    class CustomBlock extends Component {

      openURL (url) {
        Linking.openURL(url).catch(err => console.error('An error occurred', err));
      }

      render () {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
            {blockContent.map((item) => {
              switch (item.type) {
                case 'text':
                  return (
                    <View style={{padding: item.wrapperPadding}}>
                      <Text style={{fontSize: item.size, color: item.color}}>{item.content}</Text>
                    </View>
                  );
                case 'link':
                  return (
                    <TouchableHighlight style={{padding: item.wrapperPadding}} underlayColor="lightgrey" onPress={this.openURL.bind(this, item.url)}>
                      <Text style={{fontSize: item.size, color: item.color}}>{item.content}</Text>
                    </TouchableHighlight>
                  );
              }
             })}
            </View>
        );
```

It's quite easy to declare all components you expect to use like I did with text and link, and to style them as well.