# React Native render Components from String variable

Tags: javascript, react-native, jsx

Or maybe the question should have been, How to convert string to JSX?

In any case, I am trying to do a performance hack on my react native app that requires me to render React native components from a string variable.

For instance,

```
let item = "<View>
  <Text>
      This is an item
  </Text>
</View>";
```

Now in my render function, I want to render it like so:

```
render() {
    return (
      <View>
        {item}
      </View>
    );
}
```

As it is now if I try to run the application it gives an error because I am trying to render text inside a `View` component. If I try to wrap the item inside text before rendering, It just renders the item as plain text on the screen, with all the `<View>` and `<Text>` tags as strings.

How can I then render this so that the tags from the string behave as normal React Native component instead of just appearing as strings?

I have searched all over but haven't found a solution.

I will appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42652785/how-to-change-a-string-in-react-native-into-a-component

Comment: @Awa Melvine, Same problem not, found any solution if you found any kindly please share it

Comment: @Awa Melvine any updates on this question please??

Comment: @Muhammad if u got a solution please consider sharing it

Answer (score 2):

Try one of these two packages:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/acorn-jsx

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-jsx-parser

Both allow to parse  a string to jsx on the fly (Have no chance to test in RN, but for React in web works fine )

Answer (score 0):

If you put object instead of string you can easily set it inside view. But if you want to use string, you have to write a converter and extract each element as string and check and convert to it's equivalent view.
If your views have props you have to convert them also(it will be a little bit harder!)

Answer (score 0):

I think the only solution for this problem, is to declare your variable like so :

```
var str = <Detail_page1/>
```

and then wrap it with a view like this :

```
<View> {str} </View>
```