# How to parse string into react-native Component?

Tags: javascript, regex, reactjs, react-native, jsx

I want to parse a string containing `jsx` into `react-native` Component

Example:

```
const str1 = "Hi I am default text <Text style={{fontWeight: 'bold'}}>I am bold text</Text>";
```

Now I want to render it like below:

```
const App = props => {

  return (
     <View>
       <Text> {str1} </Text>
     </View>
  );
}
```

I should note that, the above code works if I change it to:

```
const str2 = <Text>Hi I am default text <Text style={{fontWeight: 'bold'}}>I am bold text</Text></Text>;
```

but per my condition `str1` can be only string, because I am taking it from `TextInput Component`.

**Expectation**: `str1` should be parsed like below:

Hi I am default text **I am bold text**

**What is my goal ?**

I want to create a post, within my app, think the post text is:

Hi friends How are you please ***Like*** the post.

As you can see ***Like*** is bold an italic, so I want to make something like this.

Comment: I render string as per your requirement and it works nothing harm in it.

Comment: @WaheedAkhtar, please render `str1` will you see string as `red` color without tag?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Render HTML string as real HTML in a React component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39758136/render-html-string-as-real-html-in-a-react-component)

Comment: @Fraction, thank you and no it is not my question, this is in `react-native`

Comment: @Muhammad I render `str1` but didn't see string as red at all.
here is the `stri1`
`'Hi I am default text <Text style={{color: 'red'}}>I am red text</Text>'`

Comment: that's the problem, it should be parsed to `Hi I am default text I am red text`

Comment: but `I am red text`, should be red

Comment: Now, I have edited may you understand better

Comment: customize your component to handle 2 strings might be the solution for your scenario.

Comment: @SDushan, it is an example, there is many more Component within the string

Comment: Oops, then you have to use something like ```react-native-webview``` to render multiple ```jsx``` inside your component.

Comment: are you trying to make a dynamic `style` for your markdown?

Comment: @HagaiHarari, yeah roughly, I just gonna style a `text` even the `app` gets built. example I publish the app, people download it, then open it. then they want to create a new lesson, then they gonna give some `style` like `color, font` to the text then save it and it will be saved to db, then it will be displayed in `UI` here the style will be apear.

Comment: @Muhammad Your question seems similar to this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51608770/react-native-render-components-from-string-variable. Checkout its answers

Comment: @AyushNawani yeah it is same, but there is not a solution for that too