# How can I make React Native render JSX tags inside a string fetched from an API source?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, jsx

I have text in a database on a server which I'm fetching using Axios and then displaying on a page in an app.  I would like to have styling in the text in the database but when I display it, the JSX tags just get written out completely instead of being rendered.

In my database I have a TEXT field containing:

```
 This is the first line
 This is the <Text style={{ fontSize: 20 }}>second</Text> line with a part in 20px
```

In my app I show the text like this:

```
 <Text>{ results.length>0 ? results[0].body : '' }</Text>
```

I would expect it to have the word "second" in bold but it just prints the tags as they appear in the text like this:

```
This is the first line
This is the <Text style={{ fontSize: 20 }}>second</Text> line with a part in 20px
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Maybe this is helpful for you somehow https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51608770/react-native-render-components-from-string-variable

Comment: @Dominique can you please some more code snippet as nested `Text` component works fine as described [here](https://reactnative.dev/docs/text#nested-text).

Comment: @Rohit Nested text does obviously work, but that is not the problem I have.