# Render a staring as a component in React Native

Tags: react-native, components

I have an endpoint that returns an RN component as the response. (`<Text> Blah Blah </Text>`).
How can I render the responded component in the app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a function that transforms the string into a component. [This link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42654754/8898886) explains how. for example:

```
 var str = <Text>test</Text>;

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        {str}
      </View>
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use js `eval` function to convert string to executable javascript code. 
e.g

```
let x="console.log('test')";
eval(x); //test
```

Since you want it to work with JSX, you can transpile the code with something like [Babel](http://babeljs.io/docs/usage/options/) before you execute it.

For example, when using the browser version of Babel:

```
var jsCode = babel.transform(jsxCode);
eval(jsCode.code);
```

There's also a run method you can use to simply execute the code:

```
babel.run(code);
```

Both transform and run take an optional options hash; check the [documentation](http://babeljs.io/docs/usage/options/) for more details.

BTW it's not a good practise as it's unsafe to transpile code in realtime. [Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval#dont-use-it)

Comment: Thanks. and how can I embed the  `babel.run(code)` in my component?

Answer (score 1):

I highly recommend you implement the components in implementation time, and switch them with the result of your endpoint.

Implementing components with eval are not efficient and the computation is very slow, by experience.

Comment: I can't implement components because I need to be dynamic