# How to transfer response error message from console to <p>

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an API connected to my app which provides me with `login()` function. Every time when email or password is wrong I get a message in console.
[image: My console:]

I have `<p>` element where I want to show this message. I tried some things, but had no success.

Part of component where I want to get that message:

```
const [errorMessage, setErrorMessage] = useState('')

const handleSubmit = event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    try {
        login(email.value, password.value, () => navigate(fromPage, {replace: true}))
    } catch (e) {
        setErrorMessage(e)
    }
}
```

My `login()` function:

```
const login = async (email, password, cb) => {
    try {
        const response = await AuthService.login(email, password);
        console.log(response)
        localStorage.setItem('token', response.data.accessToken);
        setIsAuth(true);
        setUser(response.data.user);
        cb();
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e.response?.data?.message);
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried displaying a state in the <p> and then setting that state to the error message in the login catch statement?

Answer (score 1):

When statements are wrapped in the try-catch block the error is not being propagated further, so to catch the error on a component level you need to either omit the try-catch block from the `login` function or re-throw the error:

```
const login = async (email, password, cb) => {
    try {
        const response = await AuthService.login(email, password);
        console.log(response)
        localStorage.setItem('token', response.data.accessToken);
        setIsAuth(true);
        setUser(response.data.user);
        cb();
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e.response?.data?.message);
        throw (e.response?.data?.message || 'Unknown error');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to remove try-catch statement from your `login` function and await it. This will allow try-catch statement in the `handleSubmit` to handle api errors.

Another option is to return an error or error message in your `login` function:

```js
const login = async (email, password, cb) => {
    try {
        // ...
    } catch (e) {
        return new Error(e.response?.data?.message)
    }
}
```

Then you could use the value to update your `errorMessage` state:

```js
const [errorMessage, setErrorMessage] = useState('')

const handleSubmit = async event => {
    event.preventDefault();

    const response = await login(email.value, password.value, () => navigate(fromPage, {replace: true}))

    if (response instanceof Error)
        setErrorMessage(e)
}
```

Comment: Another option is to re-throw error from `login` as suggested in https://stackoverflow.com/a/70296587/6036154

Answer (score 0):

Solved: transfered my setter into login function:

```
const login = async (email, password, cb, setError) => {
    try {
        const response = await AuthService.login(email, password);
        console.log(response)
        localStorage.setItem('token', response.data.accessToken);
        setIsAuth(true);
        setUser(response.data.user);
        cb();
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e.response?.data?.message);
        setError(e.response?.data?.message);
    }
}
```

Handler:

```
const handleSubmit = event => {
        event.preventDefault();
        login(email.value, password.value, () => navigate(fromPage, {replace: true}), setErrorMessage)

    }
```

Comment: Since you're already using async-await syntax you could get rid of callbacks entirely. It will help increase code readability and structure. I would suggest choosing a single approach(e.g. using callbacks, promises or promises with async/await) and go with it.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you wanna do this [React Native : how to change <Text> value dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41139643/react-native-how-to-change-text-value-dynamically)

after catch be called you shoud set the state of your prop. Eg on link

```
      this.setState({errorMessage: e.response?.data?.message})
```

and then use errorMessage on that < p >

```
 {this.state.errorMessage}
```